# Scroll Infinito ASP NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde, estou implementando uma lista infinita em asp net mvc e tenho algumas dúvidas sobre qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso.
Eu implementei usando partial view, fazendo uma requisição via ajax e retorno essa partial view e dou um append no meu html e esta funcionando bem.
Mas eu vi também que é possível fazer isso, retornando um JSON com os dados e montar isso via javascript e exibir pro usuário, qual seria a melhor maneira? JSON ou partial view?

Comment: É a "mesma" coisa só que ao invés de fazer um request por página, retornando o html renderizado para ser exibido, você faria a mesma coisa com um JSon e deixaria o JavaScript montar esse html. Ou você faz um único request para trazer todo o conteúdo dessa página no JSON e só controla a exibição

Comment: PartialView já vem prontinho pra fazer o *append*, se receber o `json` o retorno deve ser mais rápido e leve, porém vai ter de gerar o html todo no javascript, vc decide :)

Comment: Então as duas formas são corretas, talvez com json fique um pouco mais rápido, beleza era isso mesmo que queria saber, sou um pouco noiado com desempenho e boas praticas

Comment: Mesmo que venha como json, você ainda vai ter o processamento de montar o html e dar append cara. A diferença é que, se você trouxer todo o JSON de uma vez só, você vai ter um carregamento desnecessário de informação que pode nunca ser exibida. Se você usar uma partialview e dar append, vai ser mais rápido, pois se você olhar a implementação da engine do Razor, verá que é bem feito a montagem do html. :) Tudo tem um custo, seja de processamento (cliente ou servidor) ou rede (transferir mais dados). Seja noiado com desempenho, mas não tanto se não for uma questão crítica.

Comment: é assim que estou fazendo, carrego de de 30 em 30 os itens e cada vez que preciso buscar mais, eu vou pego a posição atual e busco no banco a partir dessa posição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, faça consulta paginada no banco de dados, se você estiver usando o Sql Server, a partir da versão 2012 o modelo é esse:

```
 select count(1) over() as total,column1,column2 from mytbale
where 1=1 
group by column1,column2
order by column1 offset @0 rows fetch next @1 rows only;
```

A cada vez que você fizer uma nova requisição, você pode passar dois parâmetros pra informar a quantidade de rows que você quer exibir, ex: no lugar de @0 você informa a partir de qual registro você quer buscar, e no lugar de @1 você informa até quando você quer buscar, no caso de mostrar de 30 em 30 registro seria: @0=0 e @1=30, depois na segunda requisição, @0=31 e @1=60, e assim por diante. A variável "total" na consulta vai conter a quantidade total de registros localizados. Isso te ajuda muito em performance.